# Dynamically create table within several for loops in jQuery

Tags: jquery, html, loops, html-table

I am trying to create a dynamic table in jQuery using a few objects of data I have.

An example of what I am trying to achieve is in this [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/pooshonk/kz2xbxy3/8/)

I have the following objects of data

This is used to map the database data (fieldMapping) to the correct cell name on the table

```
[{
     "input_source_type":"input",
     "field_id":"100786",
     "field_name":"name",
     "input_id":{"List Table":"Label 1 ref"},
     "input_ref":"Label 1 ref"
},
{   
     "input_source_type":"input",
     "field_id":"100787",
     "field_name":"desc",
     "input_id":{"List Table":"Label 2 ref"},
     "input_ref":"Label 2 ref"
},
{   
     "input_source_type":"input",
     "field_id":"100788",
     "field_name":"desc",
     "input_id":{"List Table":"Label 3 ref"},
     "input_ref":"Label 3 ref"
},
{
     "input_source_type":"input",
     "field_id":"100786",
     "field_name":"name",
     "input_id":{"List Table":"Label 4 ref"},
     "input_ref":"Label 4 ref"
},
{   
     "input_source_type":"input",
     "field_id":"100787",
     "field_name":"desc",
     "input_id":{"List Table":"Label 5 ref"},
     "input_ref":"Label 5 ref"
},
{   
     "input_source_type":"input",
     "field_id":"100788",
     "field_name":"desc",
     "input_id":{"List Table":"Label 6 ref"},
     "input_ref":"Label 6 ref"
}]
```

This is the table data (fields) - essentially there can be 2 columns max per row. The following has a list of arrays, each array being a row

```
[
    ["Label 1 ref"],
    ["Label 2 ref","Label 3 ref"],
    ["Label 4 ref","Label 5 ref"],
    ["Label 6 ref"]
]
```

Each DataStrucutre is created from a database call, along with an ID and fields. The fields are linked from the field_name key on the fieldMapping object above.
This is the data variable, a basic example image is [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xo7Hk.jpg)

This is my example code

```
for (var i in data)
{
    if (row instanceof DataStructure)
        {
            for (var i in fields)
            {
                var fieldRef = fields[i];

                for (var f in this.fieldMapping) 
                {
                    if (this.fieldMapping[f].input_id instanceof Object) 
                    {
                        var colspan = 1;
                        if(fieldRef.length == 1)
                            colspan = 2;

                        var fieldName = '';
                        for (var x in this.fieldMapping[f].input_id) 
                        {
                            fieldName = x;
                        }

                        var fName = this.fieldMapping[f].field_name;
                        if (fName == "ID")
                            fName = "id";

                        var cellValue = row.getValue(fName);

                        if (cellValue instanceof DataVariant)
                        {
                            if(colspan == 1)
                            {
                                if(fieldRef[0] && fieldRef[1])
                                {
                                    html += '<tr>';

                                    for (var r in fieldRef)
                                    {
                                        if(fieldRef[r] == this.fieldMapping[f].input_id[fieldName])
                                        {
                                            html += '<td>'+cellValue.getData()+'</td>';
                                        }
                                    }

                                    html += '</tr>';
                                }

                            }
                            else if (colspan == 2)
                            {
                                if (fieldRef == this.fieldMapping[f].input_id[fieldName])
                                {
                                    html += '<tr>';
                                    html += '<td colspan="2">'+cellValue.getData()+'</td>';
                                    html += '</tr>';
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I am trying to get the result of the [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/pooshonk/kz2xbxy3/8/) above, but I keep getting the following ([Fiddle2](https://jsfiddle.net/pooshonk/29Lphpve/2/))

```
<table>
<tr>
<td colspan="2">Title info</td>
</tr>
<tr>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>This is the main body of the map info window component.</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>54.991987, -1.522710</td>
</tr>
<tr></tr>
<tr></tr>
<tr></tr>
<tr></tr>
<tr></tr>
<tr></tr>
<tr>
<td>This is the title for the second map component</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>This is the main body of the map info window component.</td>
</tr>
<tr></tr>
<tr>
<td colspan="2">54.991987, -1.522710</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

I know this is because the amount of loops I am using that is causing the issue. How can I change this to get me to the desired result?

Any help or guidance in the right direction would be greatly appreciated

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

```
        1) Table in HTML at runtime using jQuery. The columns, rows and cells will be dynamically created in the Table using jQuery.

        2) Below is the HTML Markup of the page which consists of an HTML Button to create the dynamic HTML Table and an HTML DIV which will 
        hold the dynamically created table.



        <input type="button" id = "btnGenerate" value="Generate Table" />
        <hr />
        <div id="dvTable">
        </div>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">
        $(function () {
            $("#btnGenerate").click(function () {
                //Build an array containing Customer records.
                var customers = new Array();
                customers.push(["Customer Id", "Name", "Country"]);
                customers.push([1, "John Hammond", "United States"]);
                customers.push([2, "Mudassar Khan", "India"]);
                customers.push([3, "Suzanne Mathews", "France"]);
                customers.push([4, "Robert Schidner", "Russia"]);

                //Create a HTML Table element.
                var table = $("<table />");
                table[0].border = "1";

                //Get the count of columns.
                var columnCount = customers[0].length;

                //Add the header row.
                var row = $(table[0].insertRow(-1));
                for (var i = 0; i < columnCount; i++) {
                    var headerCell = $("<th />");
                    headerCell.html(customers[0][i]);
                    row.append(headerCell);
                }

                //Add the data rows.
                for (var i = 1; i < customers.length; i++) {
                    row = $(table[0].insertRow(-1));
                    for (var j = 0; j < columnCount; j++) {
                        var cell = $("<td />");
                        cell.html(customers[i][j]);
                        row.append(cell);
                    }
                }

                var dvTable = $("#dvTable");
                dvTable.html("");
                dvTable.append(table);
            });
        });
        </script>



      (1)First an Array has to be created which will contain the Table  Header and Cell values.  Then a Table element is created using jQuery.


      (2)(adding the header row)
```

The Header Row will be built using the first element of the Array as it contains the Header column text values.
First a row is inserted into the Table and then using the count of columns a loop is executed and one by one Table TH element is created and appended to the header row using jQuery.

```
      (3)(Table insertRow Method)
```

This method adds a new row to a Table at the specified index. If the index is supplied as -1 then the row will be added at the last position.

```
      (4) (Adding the Data Rows)
```

A loop is executed over the array elements and one by one a Row is created in the HTML Table. Then inside each Row a dynamic cell element is created and appended using jQuery

```
      (5) (Adding the dynamic Table to the Page)
```

Finally the dynamically created table is added to the page by appending it the HTML DIV using jQuery

```
      note:-You can also append an element to the body but then you won’t be able to set its placement on the page. Using a container such a DIV helps us add the dynamic element to the desired place.[enter image description here][1]
```

Comment: This is nice but this isn't what I asked for. Depending on the length of the array, i need to create either 2 columns or 1 per row. You didn't even use my example